# ExpressJS + PassportJS + passport-google-oauth `req.isAuthenticated()` returning false immediately after login

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

My [PassportJS](http://www.passportjs.org/) setup doing something weird, I can see `req.user` after logged-in in the `deserialize` function but after all `req.isAuthenticated()` `false` and no `req.user` found. I have already referred a bunch of questions regarding this issue on StackOverflow, almost every question on StackOverflow. Nothing works for me, not sure what is the case here. I'm posing my code, can someone pls tell me what is wrong here and why it's happening. At least a fix! :(

I'm using [passport-google-oauth](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth/) as my strategy. Also, the client is an Angular app.

I also tried with [passport-google-oauth20](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth20/) by accessing directly.

> What I found is, in `social_logins.google_callback` the `req.user` can
> be found and also `req.isAuthenticated()` returns `true`. After the
> redirect happens it won't work.

Thanks in advance!

```
// app.js
const pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
app.set('trust proxy', 1);

/** @type {session.CookieOptions} */
const cookieOptions = {
    path: '/',
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: false,
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 30 days
};

app.use(session({
    secret: require('./config').session.secret, // session secret
    cookie: cookieOptions,
    proxy: true,
    name: config.session.name,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new pgSession({
        pool: db.pool,
        tableName: 'sess'
    }),
}));
require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// passport.js
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

// passport login.js
app.get('/social-logins/connect/google', passport.authenticate('google-login', {
    successRedirect: '/social-logins/google',
    failureRedirect: '/social-logins/google',
    scope: ['profile', 'email'],
    failureFlash: true,
}));

// routes/index.js
router.get('/social-logins/google', social_logins.google_callback);
// callback funtion
social_logins.google_callback = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { user } = req;
        if (!user) return res.redirect('https://localhost:3000/auth/login?message=Login Failed');
        const url = `https://localhost:3000/auth/dashboard`;
        req.session.save(() => {
            return res.redirect(url);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        log_error(error);
        res.redirect(`https://localhost:3000/auth/login?error=true`);
    }
};

// passport strategy
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
module.exports = new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: 'https://localhost:3000/social-logins/connect/google',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    try {
        const acc = {}; // find from db and assign db.query('select * from users where id = $1', [profile.id]);
        return done(false, acc, { message: 'User successfully logged in' });
    } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by setting `domain` to `cookieOptions`.